# Print Numbers with For Loop on New Lines

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I can't figure out why the numbers aren't printing on new lines here.

```js
function display(min, max) {
  for (var i = min; i <= max; i++)
    document.writeln(i);
}
```

Comment: They are. You're just not formatting them. Use `body { white-space: pre-wrap; }` in your CSS.

Comment: At least in the code you have shared, you are not invoking the method at first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html automatically removes white space and line breaks, in the document it jump lines, you should use html markup instead to jump lines like this -

```
document.write(1+'<br>')
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `<br>` tag to the output.

```js
function display(min, max) {
    for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        document.writeln(i + '<br>');
    }
}

display(5, 7);
```

None the less, you could make use of the `<pre>` tag, which respects newline from [`document.writeln()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/writeln)

```js
function display(min, max) {
    document.write('<pre>');
    for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        document.writeln(i);
    }
    document.write('</pre>');
}

display(5, 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add < br /> in order to be displayed on the next row. The html engine is adding all in the same space.